# How do I re-time a periodic MD RAID check to get it started sometime else?

Tags: systemctl

I've got an MD RAID (level 10) on my SOHO server (running OpenSuSE 15.5), which undergoes a  lengthy check (> 3 hours for some 1 TB net) every Sunday at 1:00 AM local time. As the server does not run 24/7, but only when necessary, I'd like to re-time the check, so that it gets started when it makes more sense, and maybe only once in two weeks and not every week. Cronjobs apparently no longer exist on my system, but `systemctl` supports planned tasks, and the RAID check is one of them:

```sh
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  sudo systemctl list-timers mdcheck_start
NEXT                         LEFT        LAST PASSED UNIT                ACTIVATES            
Sun 2023-09-10 01:00:00 CEST 6 days left n/a  n/a    mdcheck_start.timer mdcheck_start.service

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

How can I change the timer?

**UPDATE:** Apparently I've also got a second timer regarding the MD RAID check:

```sh
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  sudo systemctl list-timers mdcheck_continue
NEXT                         LEFT    LAST PASSED UNIT                   ACTIVATES               
Mon 2023-09-04 01:05:00 CEST 6h left n/a  n/a    mdcheck_continue.timer mdcheck_continue.service

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

**But:** The file `systemctl` presents me only consists of comments:

```ini
### Editing /etc/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer.d/override.conf
### Anything between here and the comment below will become the new contents of the file

### Lines below this comment will be discarded

### /usr/lib/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer
# #  This file is part of mdadm.
# #
# #  mdadm is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
# #  under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# #  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# #  (at your option) any later version.
# 
# [Unit]
# Description=MD array scrubbing
# 
# [Timer]
# OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 1:00:00
# 
# [Install]
# WantedBy= mdmonitor.service
# Also= mdcheck_continue.timer
```

**UPDATE:** After adding these two lines to the abovementioned file:

```ini
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sat *-*-* 23:00:00
```

…the RAID check now starts twice, so I've basically added another run instead of replacing the old one. Why?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As I said, it's a SOHO (= small office, home office) installtion, not a hobbyist one.

Comment: `systemctl edit mdcheck_start.timer`. But, read up on the details, because it's not super intuitive. Also do the same for `mdcheck_continue.timer`

Comment: Thank you for your comment on the continue timer. I've also gotta edit it, right?

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently I've found the solution: First, I had to stop both timers, like this:

```sh
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  systemctl stop mdcheck_continue.timer
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  systemctl stop mdcheck_start.timer
```

Then I edited both `override.conf` files:

```sh
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  nano /etc/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer.d/override.conf
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  nano /etc/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.timer.d/override.conf
```

…as follows:

```
  GNU nano 7.2               /etc/systemd/system/mdcheck_start.timer.d/override.conf                          
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 00:00:00

  GNU nano 7.2             /etc/systemd/system/mdcheck_continue.timer.d/override.conf                         
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Sun *-*-* 00:05:00
```

After that, of course, I performed a `daemon-reload` and restarted both timers. Result:

```sh
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  systemctl list-timers mdcheck_start                   
NEXT                         LEFT        LAST PASSED UNIT                ACTIVATES            
Sun 2023-10-01 00:00:00 CEST 2 days left n/a  n/a    mdcheck_start.timer mdcheck_start.service

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
╭─root@valen ~  
╰─➤  systemctl list-timers mdcheck_continue
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST PASSED UNIT                   ACTIVATES               
Fri 2023-09-29 01:05:00 CEST 2h 15min left n/a  n/a    mdcheck_continue.timer mdcheck_continue.service

1 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```